# Growth of my plant

Tags: growth

It's been a year since I bought this plant.
When I had bought this it had only 2 leaves and was tiny.
I then transferred it into a big pot.
It then grew quite fast but from past 4-5 months it's not growing anymore. There are no new leaves I can see coming. It's just as it is. Though it is not dying but what about its growth?

I have kept this plant in my balcony.
Location is Delhi, India.
I daily water this plant.

The plant is dusty Miller.
[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Answer (score 2):

Waterning daily may be too much, I'd slowly cut back on watering the plant a little. I'd suggest fertilizing your plant if you aren't doing that already.

Comment: Thanks. No, I am not fertilizing the plant. Due to the pandemic it's not possible to go outside and buy fertilizers. Can I use manure instead? Also I don't know how much watering is excess and how much is optimal? For this plant, I water approximately half of a tumbler every morning

Comment: You can cut holes on the bottom of the container, and put a tray of water underneath. This way the soil will soak up the water if it is dry, but not if it is wet.

Answer (score 1):

What I think the best way to water a plant is cut holes at the bottom of the container and put a tray with water underneath it. The bottommost dirt will first soak up the water, then the dirt above will soak water from it, and so on, transporting waves of water to the plant. If the soil is already wet it won't soak up any water, resulting in no overwatering. The source is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eLACnABG2LM).